# Select and WHERE using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have following classes:

```
public class CatalogResponseRootObject
{
    public Plans Plans { get; set; }
}

public class Plans
{
    public List<Plan> plan { get; set; }
}

public class Plan
{
    public List<PlanPackage> Packages { get; set; }
}
public class PlanPackage
{
    public List<Package2> Package { get; set; }
}
public class Package2
{        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have a working query. But Now I am trying use Where clause to get list of those`cPlans` WHERE `Package2.Name == "Annual"`. Is it possible to retrieve such information using the `Where` clause and how?

```
CatalogResponseRootObject catalogResponse = response;
qualifiedPlans = (from cPlans in catalogResponse.Plans.plan
                                  join qPlans in conversationIDResponsePlans.plan on cPlans.Id equals qPlans.Id
                                  select cPlans).ToList();
```

Comment: What type is `conversationIDResponsePlans` ?

Comment: @Gusdor `Plans`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So plans have packages that have packages and there should be at least one that has the `Name` "Annual"? You can add a condition:

```
where cPlans.Packages.Any(p1 => p1.Package.Any(p2 => p2.Name == "Annual"))
```

This will return the plans that have at least one package with at least one package that has the name "Annual".

Comment: Thanks but I'm confused as to where would I place the where clause in my query?

Comment: @zariakhan Before `select` and after `join`